# How to customize JSON Field in django admin

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a Postrges JSON field in my model which is used to store nested json data. I want to reformat it on django admin to either open in a editor or some reformatted json which is readable by someone having 0 knowledge of JSON

I have tried using django_json_widget like this

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import JSONField
from django.contrib import admin
from django_json_widget.widgets import JSONEditorWidget

class MyModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        JSONField: {'widget': JSONEditorWidget},
    }
```

But this is just showong me empty space in place of field content like this[image]

The data stored in context field is of this format:

```
{
   "type":"product",
   "products":[
      {
         "id":"b9757d05-1b33-4ce3-aaa4-4d20480253f3",
         "mrp":65000.0,
         "tax":null,
         "upc":null,
         "name":"Macobook Air",
         "isbn_number":null,
         "display_name":"Macobook air",
         "product_type":"goods",
      }
   ],
   "variant_detail":{
      
   }
}
```

How can I show it in a proper way?

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONField: {'widget': JSONEditorWidget()},
```

Try this